# How to score glass to shine straight horizontal laser line through

Tags: laser, level

I’m trying to make a DIY laser level, I took apart a cheap one to see how to shape a laser spot into straight lines, it turns out that a simple laser beam passes through a small piece of glass (or plastic) that is scored to the desired shape.

I tried many ways to replicate the shape but the results are horrendous.

Does anybody have and ideas on how to do it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing whatsoever to do with electrical engineering.

Comment: I would just buy one, though.

Comment: Is it a scored piece of glass or a diffractive element?  I've seen both refractive and diffractive elements used in laser projectors, and it isn't clear to me which you are thinking of.

Comment: I have glass and acrylic, I don’t what’s usually used in the commercial ones

Comment: Sounds like a diffraction grating to me. I don't know if a mechanical jig would be enough. That would involve like super precise lead-screws to increment things and something else to guide your ridiculously fine scoring tool.

Answer (score 1):

Cheap pointer ones are typically just injection molded acrylic Fresnel cylinder lenses.  I have a bunch with a T-shaped arrangement of cylinders to project a crosshair (handy for alignment). They are **not** holograms or diffraction gratings. Below is a photo of one of the line generating ones.

[image]

Of course this lens goes after the usual collimating lens.

---

For better uniformity, Powell lenses, invented by Ian Powell at Canada's National Research Council in the 1980s, can be used.

You can refer to [this](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20490126/) paper. The surface is described by this equation:

[image]
Catalog page from Thorlabs.

[image]

---

If you wanted to try to duplicate the cylinder Fresnel lens, maybe you could try milling cylindrical grooves into  acrylic using a 0.8mm ball end mill then solvent vapor polishing. Probably water coolant and fairly high spindle RPM (20,000-ish).

---

Comment: I actually remember seeing a video on YouTube passing a laser through a cylindrical glass to achieve a straight line, i did a rough experiment with a broken glass tube and and I got a straight line, I tried make a cross with two tubes but I couldn’t get a cross shape. Where did you get the t-shaped lense?

Comment: The crosshair lenses just butt one set of grooves up against the side of the other and aim the laser near the intersection. Works fairly well.